# React error when using audio.play() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, jsx

I'm trying to play a sound by triggering the function with onClick event in React and I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
>
> at B (index.js:1582)
>
> at G (index.js:1899)
>
> at eval (index.js:1914)
>
> at eval (index.js:1933)
>
> at eval (index.js:1414)

```
import React from "react";
import firebase from "../../firebase";
import classes from "./Sidenav.module.sass";

const Sidenav = props => {
  const logout = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    window.location.href = "..";
  };

  const playAudio = () => {
    let audio = new Audio("../../assets/bellNotification.mp3");
    audio.play();
  };

  return (
    <div style={props.styles.sideNavDiv} className={classes.sidenavDiv}>
      <i />
      <div style={props.styles.iconDiv} className={classes.iconDiv}>
        <i className={"material-icons " + classes.navIcon}>account_box</i>
        <p className={classes.iconText}>Account</p>
      </div>
      <div style={props.styles.iconDiv} className={classes.iconDiv}>
        <i className={"material-icons " + classes.navIcon}>settings</i>
        <p className={classes.iconText}>Settings</p>
      </div>
      <div style={props.styles.iconDiv} className={classes.iconDiv}>
        <i className={"material-icons " + classes.navIcon}>trending_up</i>
        <p className={classes.iconText}>Check Progress</p>
      </div>
      <div style={props.styles.iconDiv} className={classes.iconDiv}>
        <i className={"material-icons " + classes.navIcon}>looks_one</i>
        <p className={classes.iconText}>1RM calculator</p>
      </div>
      <div
        onClick={props.toggleModal}
        style={props.styles.iconDiv}
        className={classes.iconDiv}
      >
        <i className={"material-icons " + classes.navIcon}>alarm</i>
        <p className={classes.iconText}>Edit timers</p>
      </div>
      <div
        onClick={playAudio}
        style={props.styles.iconDiv}
        className={classes.iconDiv}
      >
        <i className={"material-icons " + classes.navIcon}>help</i>
        <p className={classes.iconText}>Help</p>
      </div>
      <div
        onClick={logout}
        style={props.styles.iconDiv}
        className={classes.iconDiv}
      >
        <i className={"material-icons " + classes.navIcon}>
          power_settings_new
        </i>
        <p className={classes.iconText}>Logout</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidenav;
```

Comment: What's the name of your file? Any more code you could show as it may not be related. It looks to me to be maybe an env or react error. Try reinstalling ReactJS if you can.

Comment: I don't think the rest of my code have any impact on this function because I deliberately created a new component to test if it may be the fault of my code. I think  that reinstalling React seems reasonable, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Open your browsers network tab and see if the request for the mp3 file is pointing at the correct url.

Comment: The path is correct it is probably some problem caused by React

Comment: Can you share the full component code? Meanwhile, you can also try html5 audio tag and see whether your mp3 is getting loaded.

Comment: I updated the code so now it show the whole component. After reinstalling react and updating react-scripts I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 11):

The same thing happened to me also because of the chrome changes in player promise.
just replace your `player.play()` with

```
const playPromise = player.play();

      if (playPromise !== undefined) {
        playPromise
          .then(_ => {
            // Automatic playback started!
            // Show playing UI.
            console.log("audio played auto");
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // Auto-play was prevented
            // Show paused UI.
            console.log("playback prevented");
          });
      }
```

You can read more about it [here on chrome blogs about player promise changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted)

Comment: thanks bro.. it works smooth like a butter :ok:

Answer (score 2):

use `import audio from '../assets/audio.mp3'//your map3 path there`
then create an object `let audio = new Audio(audio)`
and play the sound in the desired function `audio.play()`

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I managed to fix my problem. This error is caused because the `new Audio(url).play()` points to the index.html in the public folder and for some reason it doesn't seem to work in the root div in my case. I created the audio element in the index.html file and moved the mp3 file to the public folder.

`<audio id="audio"><source src="bellNotification.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source></audio>`

I changed the function like this

`const playAudio = () => {
    document.getElementById("audio").play();
 };`

It works for me but I hope that someone can fix this problem with pure js without accessing the html file.

Answer (score 0):

For me I started getting this really vague error when the audio files had been renamed.

> index.js:1 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a
> stack trace.

Please check that your audio files are matching the path and name in your code before you try different methods to play them.

Answer (score 0):

Import your audio file like this

```
import audio from './filepath'
```

just replace filepath with your audio file's location
Then create an audio and add its source in this way

```
const audioElement = new Audio()
audioElement.src = audio
```

The just play the audio

```
audioElement.play()
```