# React Audio Playback Prevented

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

In my return code for my react code I say this:

```
 {NOTES.map((note, index) => {
        return (
          <audio
            id={index}
            key={index}
            src={`../../assets/pianoSounds/${index + 1}.mp3`}
          />
        );
      })}
```

I'm just creating a bunch of audio objects in the HTML. Then in my code I say:

```
const noteAudio = new Audio(document.getElementById(index).src);   
noteAudio.play();
```

So the code gets the audio source from the HTML audio object and plays it. However I get the following error in the Chrome Console, and my audio doesn't play:
[image]

Now after some searching I landed at this [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398641/react-error-when-using-audio-play-function). However their solution doesn't actually play the sound though, it just says there is an error. How do I get the sound to play? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: I did, I provided all the code that is responsible for the audio.

Comment: That's not a [mcve].  Are you surprised no one has answered your question yet?

Comment: What I'm saying is this.  Imagine an army or React and JS engineers are standing by to answer your question.  But they need a very small project sample that they can paste into the standard `npm create-react-app` and debug your code for you.  You haven't provided what they need.